# SQL Server: How to check if the value of returned field is not null

Tags: sql-server, null

I have SQL statement as follows:

```
SELECT  ReturnDate
FROM    <joins>
WHERE   <conditions>
```

How to check if ReturnDate is not null?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `CASE` with [`IS NULL`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188795.aspx) (or `IS NOT NULL`):

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN ReturnDate IS NULL THEN 'It is null' 
         ELSE 'It is not null' 
       END AS IsItNull 
FROM   dbo.tablename ....
```

If you need to filter for `NULL/NOT NULL` values you can also use `IS NOT NULL`:

```
WHERE ReturnDate IS NOT NULL  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to select any records where it is null, use something like:

```
SELECT  ReturnDate
FROM    <joins>
WHERE   ReturnDate IS NOT NULL AND <conditions>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the returnDate with the "Is Null"

Answer (score -1):

Try this query

```
SELECT  ReturnDate
FROM    joins
WHERE   conditions AND ReturnDate IS NOT NULL;
```